# How to re-render the whole Flutter app on some event?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Is there a recommended way how to force the whole Flutter app to re-render during runtime but without losing state?
I need to update the app according to the back-end response, and I can't use the regular approaches (updating the widget state, inherited widget - provider pattern, etc.). More precisely, the data I need to update is shown on the UI via one Flutter package that does not provide the ability to trigger re-rendering in case of change (data is loaded just once on startup).

In other words, is the below-posted solution valid? Are there any known drawbacks of this approach? Can I crash the app forcing re-rendering this way?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(Wrapper(child: MyApp()));
}

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  Wrapper({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  updateIfNeeded(BuildContext context) {
    // faking some API call...
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      void rebuild(Element el) {
        el.markNeedsBuild(); // can something go wrong here?
        el.visitChildren(rebuild);
      }

      (context as Element).visitChildren(rebuild);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    updateIfNeeded(context);

    return child;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrapper(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter App',
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home Page')),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[Text('Some content...')],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on why you can't use any of the regular approaches? You certainly shouldn't need to do that recursive loop. That's what the 3 Flutter layers (widgets, elements and render objects) are optimized to do under the hood.

Comment: @Martyns I'm using a Proxy pattern to replace the original data source (adding some custom logic). That data is later used by other Flutter package (shown on the UI), and I do not have control of it. So, I would like to trigger generation in case data has been changed.

Comment: What I'd do is fork the package and include some kind of onChanged callback functionality that you could use. But 100% don't do the recursive children visiting ;)

Comment: @Martyns tnx for the quick response!  
That would be the best solution, but unfortunately, it would force other devs to use my fork instead of the original package, and probably they would not like that :(.  
That was also one of the reasons why I am thinking about the above-posted solution.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can always create a PR so that your improvement can get merged into the main repo. That way other devs would simply update to latest version from pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global key and assign it to MaterialApp key and change it's value whenever you want to refresh the app

Comment: I thought about this approach, but that would clear/reset all states below in the widgets tree, and I would like to avoid that :(

Comment: So what is the reason of re-render the whole app if you don't want to lose the states ? @Brad

Comment: I'm developing a tool that should improve developer/tester productivity. Put differently, I tend to show changes made on one platform immediately on the testing device. If they need to re-create the previous state again after the change, then I didn't provide them the best solution.